# How do I iterate through a pandas group and check to see if a string is in each group?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a bunch of records on certain dates.  I need to group them by date, and do a check to see if the next day has records that are also in the prior day, specifically I need to output what records were deleted.

Here is an example dataset:

```
Date        Item
20160101    apple
20160101    pear
20160101    banana
20160102    apple
20160102    pear
20160102    beans
```

I need to figure out the differences that occur for each date, so for this example from 01/02/2016 there is a an added string 'beans' and a 'banana' was removed from the group.

So far I have as my code:

```
groups = frame['Item'].groupby(frame['Date'])

for date, item in groups:
    for i in item:
        if i not in item[:-1]:
            print date, item, 'Deleted'
```

This doesn't seem to be working.  I should be expecting:

```
20160102 , banana, Deleted
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
diffs = frame.groupby(frame.columns.tolist()).size().unstack(fill_value=0).diff()
diffs
```

[image]

```
diffs.mask(diffs.eq(0)).stack().map({-1: 'deleted', 1: 'added'})

Date      Item  
20160102  banana    deleted
          beans       added
dtype: object
```

Comment: That's smart, bravo !

Comment: Great solution!  I am getting an issue with the fill_value part though.  It says "unstack() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value''"  Any ideas?

Comment: probably versions.  you can try `unstack().fillna(0)`

Comment: Never mind, upgrading pandas worked! Thank you very much!