# compare two pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two pandas dataframes defined as such:

```
_data_orig = [
    [1, "Bob", 3.0],
    [2, "Sam", 2.0],
    [3, "Jane", 4.0]
]
_columns = ["ID", "Name", "GPA"]

_data_new = [
        [1, "Bob", 3.2],
        [3, "Jane", 3.9],
        [4, "John", 1.2],
        [5, "Lisa", 2.2]
    ]
_columns = ["ID", "Name", "GPA"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=_data_orig, columns=_columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=_data_new, columns=_columns)
```

I need to find the following information:

- Find deletes where df1 is the original data set and df2 is the new data set
- I need to find the row changes for existing record between the two.  Example ID == 1 should compare df2's ID == 1 to see if any column value changed for each row.
- Find any adds to df2 verse df1. Example return [4, "John", 1.2] and [5, "Lisa", 2.2]

For operation to find changes in rows, I figured I could look through df2 and check df1, but that seems slow, so I'm hoping to find a faster solution there.

For the other two operations, I really do not know what to do because when I try to compare the two dataframes I get:

`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`

Pandas version: '0.16.1'

Suggestions?

Comment: you may want to check [this great solution from @piRSquared](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40229031/5741205)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***setup***

```
m = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID', 'Name'], how='outer', suffixes=['', '_'], indicator=True)
m
```

[image]

***adds***

`m.loc[m._merge.eq('right_only')]`
or
`m.query('_merge == "right_only"')`

[image]

***deletes***

`m.loc[m._merge.eq('left_only')]`
or
`m.query('_merge == "left_only"')`

[image]

---

***`0.16.1` answer***

***setup***

```
m = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID', 'Name'], how='outer', suffixes=['', '_'])
m
```

[image]

***adds***

```
m.loc[m.GPA_.notnull() & m.GPA.isnull()]
```

[image]

***deletes***

```
m.loc[m.GPA_.isnull() & m.GPA.notnull()]
```

[image]

Comment: the indicator=True seems to not be a valid parameter, is that new? I am using version '0.16.1'

Comment: @josh1234 yes!  definitely new from 0.16.1.  Is upgrading an option.  I'll get you something that works for you.  It's an easy adjustment.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot upgrade :(  If you know another way, please let me know!

Comment: this is great! thank you.  Is there a  way to look at a row, and if a row has NaN then mark it as new? or old?

Comment: Awesome examples!  Thank you so much.  This should be a frozen discussion because it's so good!

Comment: @josh1234 yes!  I'll show you one here and you can generalize `m.loc[m.GPA_.isnull() & m.GPA.notnull(), 'status'] = 'old'`

Answer (score 0):

doing this:

```
df1.set_index(['Name','ID'])-df2.set_index(['Name','ID'])
Out[108]: 
            GPA
Name ID        
Bob  1  -0.2000
Jane 3   0.1000
John 4      nan
Lisa 5      nan
Sam  2      nan
```

would allow you to screen if there is difference between df1 and df2. NaN would represent values that does not intersect

Comment: so this would work for finding GPA differences, but I have other columns like text that I also need to find differences as well.  For example address data, etc..  I just put a simplified example of my dataset in the forum.